# Move partition data to separate filegroups

Tags: sql-server

I have an existing database where hundreds of tables are using the same partitioning function and schema

```
CREATE PARTITION FUNCTION [pf](datetime2(0)) AS RANGE LEFT FOR 
VALUES (N'19901-01-01T00:00:00.000', N'1990-02-01T00:00:00.000',
N'2099-12-01T00:00:00.000')
GO
CREATE PARTITION SCHEME [ps] AS PARTITION [pf] TO ([PRIMARY], [PRIMARY], [PRIMARY])
```

For brevity I only took the first two and the last window.
As you can see, **all partitions** have been created **on the primary filegroup**.

Now the seemingly unthinkable has happened and the primary FG is full.
Data is unevenly distributed across partitions. Some are huge, some are small, some are even empty. I have been tasked to move the data as effiently as possible.

For ease of use I am thinking about creating one additional filegroup and file per decade to keep it manageable.

My question is, how would you go about moving the data out of the primary filegroup, considering hundreds of tables, including temporal ones and a multi terabyte database?
My first hunch is creating a new partitioning function and scheme matching the new file structure and then rebuild every clustered index on that new scheme.

Since it will be on table level, I could split the work to fit into multiple outage windows and do them in bunches.

Do you think this is a reasonable approach? Would you do it differently?

Answer (score 2):

> Do you think this is a reasonable approach? Would you do it differently?

No.  There's no simple way to do what you propose.  Instead why not just increase primary filegroup space, adding additional files if necessary?

Comment: I really wish that was an option. It's not, unfortunately. I absolutely have to move the data out of the first file in that filegroup. And yes, it will be a tedious and slow process, but we have to bite that bullet. The primary filegroup already consists of multiple files , some with free space. But the first logical file is filled completely and growing it is not an option any more. So we have to move data out of it. It would be even acceptable to move the data to another file in that same filegroup

Comment: Then just rebuild some indexes and the space used will start to even out across the files in the filegroup.  It's best if all the files in the filegroup have the same size and growth settings, but not a requirement.